# Do booleans require additional syntax in case when/then statements?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this simple case statement :

```
  class_name = case link_path
    when current_page?(jobs_path)               then 'current'
    when current_page?(open_estimates_path)     then 'current'
    when current_page?(tasks_path)              then 'current'
    when current_page?(calendar_dispatch_path)  then 'current'
  end
  debugger
```

At my break point, I can ask, `current_page?(tasks_path)`, and it will return `true`.

Then I ask `class_name`, and it returns `nil`.

What syntactical error am I making here?

ruby 1.9.2p136

Rails 3.0.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `case` statement doesn't do what you think it does. It compares the subject to all the values stated in the `when` branches and returns the value of the first matching one. For example:

```
color = case num_color
          when 1 then 'red'
          when 2 then 'green'
          when 3 then 'blue'
        end
```

You are giving it `link_path` as the subject, so it compares `link_path` to each of the booleans in your `when` branches. As `link_path` is probably not a boolean value, none of the branches will be evaluated. Maybe you want something like this instead:

```
class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'current' : ''
```

This will set `class_name` to `"current"` if `link_path` is the current page, otherwise to `""`.

Comment: Thanks Niklas B. I still wish there was a sexy way to write it like the case statement. I tried using the ternary statement but if you have multiples of those, then they overwrite each other. ;D Thanks again!

Comment: @Trip: If you have more than one condition, use `if/elsif`. You *could* also do something like `case true ...`, but it's going to be ugly. You can also use a Hash, depending on the use case. Maybe if you explain what you want to achieve, we can figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing string to a boolean.

`link_path` is compared against every value you put in `where` until a match is found. Here, obviously, there's no match.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a Boolean with link_path so none of the cases are going be matched. Why not use if/elsif instead?